# SQL Request With Sum and multiple Where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table contains data about visits, date of the visits, type and number of visitors. It looks like:

```
| Date_Visit | Type  | Nb_Visitors |
 04-05-2015   Intern    3
 08-09-2015   Extern    10
 13-09-2015   Intern    2
 17-09-2015   Intern    6
    ...        ...      ...
```

I would like to have as output something like this:

```
|DateMonth | Nb_Visit_Extern | Nb_Visitors_Extern | Nb_Visit_Intern | Nb_Visitors_Intern |
 05-2015     1                 3                   0                  0
 09-2015     1                 10                  2                  8
```

My query look like:

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20) As DateMonth,
COUNT(*) Nb_Visit_Extern,
SUM(Nb_Visitors) Nb_Visitors_Extern
From MyTable
Where [Type] = 'Extern'
GROUP BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20)
ORDER BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20) ASC

SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20) As DateMonth,
COUNT(*) as Nb_Visit_Intern,
SUM(Nb_Visitors) as Nb_Visitors_Intern
From MyTable
Where [Type] = 'Intern'
GROUP BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20)
ORDER BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20) ASC
```

I tried to use the CASE condition but it didn't work with the SUM statement.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple Count and Sum function of SQL.

```
    SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20) As DateMonth,
COUNT(case when Type = 'Extern' then 1 else 0 end) Nb_Visit_Extern,
SUM(case when Type = 'Extern' then [Nb_Visitors] else 0 end) Nb_Visitors_Extern,
COUNT(case when Type = 'Intern' then 1 else 0 end) Nb_Visit_Intern,
SUM(case when Type = 'Intern' then [Nb_Visitors] else 0 end) Nb_Visitors_Intern
GROUP BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20)
ORDER BY CONVERT (VARCHAR(7), [Date_Visit], 20) ASC
```

Comment: If you found any problem, please mention me. Happy to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `case` expression like

```
SUM(case when Type = 'Extern' then 1 else 0 end) as Nb_Visitors_Extern
```